# cannot create my jar file after creating a docker file in my Spring application

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, dockerfile

After entering terminal:

```
./mvnw package -Dmaven.test.skip = true
```

I'm  getting this error:

> '/.mvnw' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

This can mean two things:

1. You do not have Maven installed `->` You have to install it.
2. The path to `mvnw` is not included in your Windows Path Variable. `->` You have to include it.

Comment: And 3.: You have not setup Maven Wrapper for your project (the `mvnw` wrapper script is expected to be located in the project's root). `->` You have to set it up as described [here](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper)